# HangFire / ASPNET Core - Increasing a value in RecurringJob

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

These are simple examples that will help me, and others, to understand better how HangFire works. They're seem silly questions, but I will apreciate if you could answer them.

1. I have the following method:

```
public void Print(int i)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The value of i is {0}.", i));
}
```

I need to set a RecurringJob that will start with `i = 1` and will stop when `i = 10`.

2. The same method 1, but a little different.

```
public int Print(int i)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The value of i is {0}.", i));
  
  return i++;
}
```

How to use the Print method returning value to set the next iteration of RecurringJob?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think HangFire will keep that returned value in-memory and pass it to the next iteration. But, if you want to preserve some values from the previous run, you can simply put it into some storage (Database) and use it in the next iteration.

Comment: what you can do is start one job and enqueue the next job with incremented value of i until it reaches 10